# Mysql multiple left join

Tags: mysql

We have one table say table A we left join with table B. This works fine. The issue here is that based on the left join of table A and B we would like to have another left join but between table B and table C because those fields are available only in this 2 table so what is best solution to build this query?

Comment: its the same as joining tables a and b, but the on clause is going to reference tables b and c

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can chain joins quite easily:

```
SELECT ...
FROM a
LEFT JOIN b on a.somefield=b.somefield
LEFT JOIN c on b.otherfield=c.otherfield
```

Comment: yes your solution works any tips for optimisation for this query or this the best solution ready?

Comment: This is the best solution. You can help the MySQL server to optimize by adding keys to the table

Comment: @yunzen you mean index the fields rite nothing more then rite?

Comment: Rite? What do you mean by that?

Comment: `right`? simple rule of thumb for indexes: any field used in a join, in a where clause, or an order-by should be indexed. basically anywhere the field is used in a decision-making capacity.

Comment: @marb thank you for that but sometimes we use this one field in one decision making for one query then another query we make use of other fields so should we create individual indexes or composite indexes?

Comment: depends on how you're doing things. if you're always using fields `a`, `b`, and `c` in all joins/wheres, then a composite key will work. if you'r eusing only some of the fields, then you'll have to have multiple composite keys covering all the combinations, or individual keys.